# My edit function creates a new page instead of editing the previous page views.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, cs50

I edited my views.py but I am having a bug, each time I edit the previous entry, it creates a new entry with what i edited instead of editing that copy. I've tried to retouch the possible errors. please help

VIEWS.PY

```
class AddPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Tell us more!"
        })
    
def edit_page(request, title):
    if request.method == "GET":
        content = util.get_entry(title)   
        form = AddPageForm(initial={"content": title})
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/editpage.html", 
        {"form": form})

    else:
        form = AddPageForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return redirect('encyclopedia:entrypage', title)
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/editpage.html', {'form': form})
```

EDIT PAGE

```
{% block body %}

    <h1>Edit {{ title }}</h1>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% form %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>
```

ENTRY PAGE

```
{% block body %}
        {{ content|safe }}

        <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:editpage' title=title %}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>

{% endblock %}
```

URLS.PY

```
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry_page, name="entrypage"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("add_page", views.add_page, name="addpage"),
    path("edit_page/<str:title>", views.edit_page, name="editpage")

]
```

UTILS.PY

```
def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))


def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

I am using forms.Form because this is an assignment and the requirement states that we should use that instead of forms.Model

Comment: What are the `util.get_entry` and `util.save_entry` functions and can you include the code for them? You should use a ModelForm for creating and updating instances of a model

Comment: @lain, I have updated the code to include this. The requirement for this assignment states that we should use forms.Form instead of a model

Comment: You seem to be passing the title instead of the content as the initial data of your form, is this your issue causing the `content` field when you edit to not contain the correct data from the existing entry? Not sure what you mean about creating new entries, your code purposefully deletes the previous entry and creates a new one?